# Making a JavaScript collapsible close all others when opened

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML that I build dynamically (with a Java program). I just replace the placeholders with my content then append those strings to a master HTML document and everything comes together:

```
<button class="collapsible">∆Marker1∆</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>∆Marker2∆</p>
</div>
```

I create however many of those that I need then this lower part of the document gets appended to what was created:

```
<script>
var colls = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
  for(var col of colls) {
    col.addEventListener("click", function() {

      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;

      if (content.style.maxHeight) {
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } 
      else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 

  });
}
</script>
```

I was able to figure out the code well enough to turn it into this:

```
<script>
var colls = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var dolls = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

  function closeAll() {
      for(var dol of dolls) {
        dol.classList.toggle("active");
        dol.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
  }

  for(var col of colls) {
    col.addEventListener("click", function() {

      closeAll();

      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;

      if (content.style.maxHeight) {
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } 
      else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 

  });
}
</script>
```

Which actually does what I want it to do, except I lost the "toggle" behavior of the first version of the code so that when you open one of the buttons, it opens, and when you open another one, the one that was open gets closed, then it opens the new one that was clicked.

However, when I click on an open button, it won't close.

What's the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work. You're currently always reactivating the current button.

This code checks if the current button is active before toggling other classes.

```
var colls = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var dolls = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

  function closeAll() {
      for(var dol of dolls) {
        dol.classList.remove("active");
        dol.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
  }

  for(var col of colls) {
    col.addEventListener("click", function() {

      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      
      if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
        closeAll();        
        content.style.maxHeight = 0;
      } else {
        closeAll();
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      }

  });
}
```

PS You can use colls instead of colls and dolls. The arrays contain references to the elements and since you're not modifying the arrays you can just use one.

Comment: OK, so I just copied and pasted your code and left everything I had above the iteration loop alone, including my closeAll() function and it behaves exactly the same ... still cant close an open button.

Comment: I just made a small change to closeAll(). This works for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/zxmc7vhf/

Comment: Here check this out ... https://jsfiddle.net/EasyGoing1/rfhep3dc/1/#&togetherjs=1fbB9Qziyo Try to close an open button

Comment: YOU GOT IT! looks like you updated your answer too. Nice work, wish I understood JS well enough to have figured that out.

Comment: And good to know about the way JS handles the array pointers. In Java, you pretty much always have the object itself so if you need to do something with it without changing anything in the original object you have to make a copy of it first.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a `data attribute` to specify if the element is closed or not.

```
[data-closed="true"] { height: 0px; }
```

Inside your `closeAll` you should close all nodes.

```
doll.dataset.closed = true
```

Inside your click handler toggle the value of `closed` as follows.

```
this.dataset.closed = !(this.dataset.closed);
```

In my opinion it's better to replace `this` with `evt.target` where `evt` is the parameter of the `click` callback. `this` is quite a complex concept is JavaScript.